# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dll

**Error:**
    Could not load file or assembly '**System.Web.Mvc**, **Version=5.2.3.0**,    **Culture=neutral**, **PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35**' or one of its dependencies. The    system *cannot find the file specified*.

```
<compilation>
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,       PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</assemblies>
</compilation>

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value     [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. 
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure   logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

my **web.config**:

```
<configuration>  
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AbbasMVCContext" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP- 584JRQR\ASUSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=AbbasMVCDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />          
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Authentication/Login"></forms>
</authentication>  
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
<remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<system.codedom>
<compilers>    
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

my **bin-address**: **Home/mywebsite.com/wwwroot/bin** on the host provider and inside bin folder:

```
roslyn  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions        
Abbas MVC.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions 
Antlr3.Runtime.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions    
BusinessEntities.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions  
BusinessLayer.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions 
DataAccessLayer.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions   
EntityFramework.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions          Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions.  
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions        Newtonsoft.Json.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions
System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions 
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions
System.Web.Extensions.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions 
System.Web.Helpers.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions             
System.Web.Http.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions       
System.Web.Mvc.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions           
System.Web.Optimization.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions        
System.Web.Razor.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions       
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions     
System.Web.WebPages.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions        
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions      
ViewModel.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions       
WebGrease.dll  Rename File/Folder  Edit Permissions
```

why its not working.

Comment: Is the System.Web.Mvc.dll in your bin folder version 5.2.3.0?

Comment: I do not know . This file is created by Visual Studio 2015. How can it understand version?

Comment: The reference is almost certainly a NuGet one, so take a look at the installed packages in the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. This will show you the version that's referenced.

Comment: i did that .display version 5.2.3 .but when right click on the system.web.mvc in references properties filed run time version set value v4.0.30319 and filed version set value 5.2.3.0.

Comment: I've got to fix this. The problem was route config.

Answer (score 0):

This must be the name of the default controller and action name to change our values.
in the App_start->RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Controller name", action = "Action name", id =      UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```